# How to fix the error " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha.imgae' " in Python?

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to create Image Captcha in Python but in output I am getting the error.Could you please look into the below issue.

Code:

```
from captcha.imgae import ImageCaptcha
ic = ImageCaptcha()
ic.write("siva","one.png")
print("Captcha IMAGE is created")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\practice35.py", line 3, in <module>
    from captcha.imgae import ImageCaptcha
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha.imgae'
```

Comment: I think it should be `captcha.image`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks it's a typo and there should be `captcha.image`